# Is it possible to suggest account/question association for owners of migrated questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, linked-accounts

On Programmers we keep seeing questions migrated from other sites (usually Stack Overflow) that end up with the question's owner creating a new account and posting an answer to add additional information. The latest example I can think of is [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76289/javas-advantage-in-shopping-cart-platform).

I guess something breaks down in the association mechanism -- maybe the user doesn't register with the same OpenID or declines account association, but usually the name on the account is the same as on the question. So I wonder... would it be possible to suggest possible questions to the new user if they've been migrated and the name on them matches theirs?

Something like,

> We found the following migrated
>   questions posted by "Andrew_1510". Are they yours? Click "yes" to
>   regain ownership of them.
>
> - [Java's advantage in shopping cart platform](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76289/javas-advantage-in-shopping-cart-platform)
>
> [Yes] [No]

Or is there some other way we can clarify how account association works and what a user has to do to regain control of their question after it's been migrated?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this would allow anyone to create a matching account and claim ownership of any unowned question without proving his/her identity. However, I suppose that it might be feasible to tell them that they have to use the same OpenID if such a scenario is detected, but that might sound "too technical" for many SE sites.

Comment: Yeah, it'll be hard to find a solution that's clear enough. At the same time, I don't think the current way works very well. It's hard to explain how to correct the situation if a person created a new account and the post ownership didn't transfer automatically.