# Migration to a site where I have no account is a very bad user experience

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, usability, migrated-questions

My [question about Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/upgrade-postgres-without-messing-with-ports) got migrated from ServerFault to the DBA site. I did not yet have an account there.

Now I can’t even comment on the answers I received, let alone edit my own question (except via moderators). Presumably this is because I wasn’t already signed up to it, and this process triggers [the 100 rep bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep).

I suppose a significant share of this will go away when the 100 rep bug is fixed, so I’ll change this question to **report that I did not gain ownership of the question automatically** (as suggested in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35167/136714)).

(please dupe if this has been asked before)

Comment: Have you logged in to that site to associate your accounts?

Comment: @N.N. - good point, however there is a problem with account associations at the moment which might not be fully fixed.

Comment: @N.N. Yes. I wouldn’t mind if that happened automatically though :)

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to suggest account/question association for owners of migrated questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91267/is-it-possible-to-suggest-account-question-association-for-owners-of-migrated-qu), [How to handle a “new user” migration situation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34225/how-to-handle-a-new-user-migration-situation/), [Auto-create user account on migration of questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84657/auto-create-user-account-on-migration-of-questions)

Comment: People please hold your down votes, [this could be a bug that keeps coming up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125583/creating-account-on-new-se-site-only-1-rep-no-profile-copy), [original here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep)

Comment: @Everyone yes, it looks like that bug. I’ve made a major edit to change what this post is about.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:** The new system for dealing with association bonuses is now deployed across the network.  It's more reliable, faster, and simpler.  I also ran a backfill of association bonuses that *should* have taken care of anyone who should have one anywhere on the network (please comment here if you find an exception - I'll take a look).

Now for the bad news: I'll be running a much sadder job tomorrow to clear up a few thousand duplicate awards from the old system, which suffered from some race conditions, so a few illegitimate +200 bonuses will become +100.

---

This *is* the result of the association bonus being completely on the fritz.  Honestly I couldn't figure out what's going wrong with it after 2 hours of investigation, so I stopped.

Even *if* we fixed the current method of doing this, it would, by nature of how it works, still break - during builds, etc.  Instead of spending another several hours trying to track down what the hell's happening, we made the call yesterday to replace the mechanism that does this completely.

We did a lot of network account work several months back which means how association bonuses work can be *much* simpler all around (from a high level: we don't need to track network level things on each user).  We can now enjoy the benefits of that earlier effort in other network-level things like association bonuses.

Apologies this is taking more than a day to fix, it's just not a simple thing to do.  In addition to the core Q&A engine, it requires changes in: StackExchange.com, Area 51, Careers, StackAuth, and API v1.

We've completed most of this, but need to test and I need to write some backfills to fix people both affected in the last few days, and affected from *wayyyyyy* before that (as I said, it's always been buggy).  I hope to roll this out this afternoon/evening after we give it a good thrashing in the dev environment.

Comment: So you think people will experience 100 rep boost all of a sudden all around the network? :)

Comment: @Sha - If they're missing it, yup - and a very sparse few will also see a 100 drop (SO has 114 users who got the bonus twice...but they appear to be inactive users for the most part - the dupe "bug", really any together, is exacerbated by long bouts of inactivity)

Comment: @NickCraver I certainly do not expect you to fix it in a day :) Sorry to have changed the topic of my question three times; when you (presumably) marked this as status-planned, it seems you may have missed the fact that I edited the question again? I can edit it back and report the "question appropriation failure" in a separate post.

Comment: @romkyns - I just decided to use this as a canonical - because that's what this is causing, whether it be lack of a bonus, unmapped posts, or an empty profile on a new site...it's a crappy user experience all around.  We're now taking the time to fix that *for good*, rather than continuing to patch a leaky boat.

Comment: Cheers for all of that Nick - good luck with the new boat may it be strong and fast and shiny! :-)

Comment: Sounds fantastic, and I did get my 100 rep now. However, the question association is still broken. Were you planning to run something that’ll fix that up too?

Comment: @romkyns - yep still some backfill process that needs to be written there, but I shall get to it hopefully by this weekend (again lots of historically not-hooked-up-posts here), but I hit the button to map up your posts just now.