# Interacting with a migrated question where I don't have an account

Tags: support, migration, user-accounts

This is not a duplicate of [this Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125588/migration-to-a-site-where-i-have-no-account-is-a-very-bad-user-experience) that discusses the 100 rep association bug that was fixed a while ago.

**Note**: I just created a Beer.SE account in order to accept the answer posted, though I don't want the Beer.SE account. This question is based on a user not wanting to create an account on the migrated site in order to interact with their question, when they won't use their account on that SE site.

I asked a [question on Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/25214/does-re-refrigerating-affect-the-taste-of-beer) (this redirects) and it was migrated to [Beer.SE](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/does-re-refrigerating-affect-the-taste-of-beer).

I don't have an account on Beer.SE; since I'm not registered, I can't vote on the answer nor can I accept it. *Moreover*, the question already [has an answer!](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/605/does-beer-suffer-from-being-warmed-and-then-rechilled)

So I can't vote, I can't accept, I can't close, and I can't delete. I know that I can create an account on Beer.SE, but I know that I'll never be active on that site again. The question on Beer.SE should actually be closed as a duplicate or deleted but I can't even do that, since I'm not registered.

**Is there an easier way to interact with a migrated question where I *don't have an account*?** Or *must* I create an account even though I will never use it again?

Comment: Sorry, can't understand what's so horrible in creating new account.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The fact that my question was migrated there and I want to be responsible by voting for/accepting the answer; however, I will never do *anything else* on Beer.SE, so I really shouldn't have an account there. As well, I can't even close or delete my question without being registered (and it should be marked as dupe or deleted), and if I do so I actually have to waste the SE team's time by filing a request for account deletion. It's bad user experience, thus why I'm asking the question.

Comment: There's no harm to anyone in having an account you never use. I have dozens and they never matter in any way.

Comment: @murgatroid99 True, and that may be your prerogative, but it's not mine. I feel that I should have some amount of control over my own question when it's migrated, but in order to do so I have to create an account on a site where I don't *want* an account. Keep in mind that I didn't know Beer.SE existed and would have looked there and **found** the answer to my question without actually having to create an account that I didn't want to create.

Comment: You are of course free to feel however you like about creating a new account. But you want to take account related actions on a site where you don't have an account, and there is already a simple, easy, well-tested workflow for accomplishing that. It's unlikely that they would be able to associate posts on one site with accounts on another without making the whole system more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easier way to interact with a migrated question where I
>   don't have an account?

It's only "migrated" on Skeptics, on Beer it's essentially just a question as if you'd originally asked it on Beer.

You're essentially asking "Can I use a site even though I have not registered", well "no" that's not how the sites work, and migration does not really change the reasons for needing to register.

I see no hardship in having an account even if only for this question. How do you decide when having an account on a site is viable to you? When you will ask 5 questions? 10? When you will ask and answer 10 questions? This makes no sense, you have a question on Beer which you wanted an answer to (albeit migrated from Skeptics), is this not enough to warrant an account?

If the *single* question (now) on Beer is not enough to warrant you opening an account on Beer, then your question here (MSE) is largely pointless, as either you don't care about your question on Beer, so forget it, or just open an account because it's important to you.

---

> I feel that I should have some amount of control over my own question
>   when it's migrated

Well, it should not have been asked on the wrong site, to be fair, however in terms of your "control" you can:

1. Ask to be disassociated with the question (on Beer), i.e. if you
   would not have opened an account to ask on Beer
2. Open an account on Beer site (simple and quick to do) and manage
   your question with ease
3. Leave it and forget it ever existed

I think this is a fair amount of "control", especially when considering site "scope" and "topic" is site specific and is pretty well documented (you did ask on the wrong site).

I also don't think there should be any change in the system to somehow accommodate users being able to interact with their question migrated to a site they do not have an account with.

There are reasons we need to register and migration doesn't change this - there is no way to use the stats and privileges (etc) on the site it was migrated *from* and use them on the site it was migrated *to* - they're two different sites and you need a separate account on them both.