# Migration to a site with no account prevents quick account deletion feature

Tags: bug, migration, user-accounts, help-center, deleted-accounts

After asking [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246362/interacting-with-a-migrated-question-where-i-dont-have-an-account), I think I've stumbled across a bug.

According to all the Help pages, but [Beer.SE](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) specifically, I should be able to delete my account without assistance from the SE team as long as I *have not voted or posted more than once*.

I recently had [a question migrated to Beer.SE](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/does-re-refrigerating-affect-the-taste-of-beer) from Skeptics.SE. In order to accept the answer (though the question should be marked as a duplicate or deleted) for the effort greggle138 put into it, I created an account. But before I did anything else, I looked at what it would take to delete my account.

The only thing I have done so far on Beer.SE is, well, nothing really. The question was migrated there, I did not ask it, but it still counts as [one post](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/users/2632/chris-cirefice?tab=questions). [I haven't voted](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/users/2632/chris-cirefice?tab=votes), or even accepted the answer to my question. Thus, from what I can see, this falls under the *you have not voted or posted more than once* rule.

So, the fact that I cannot quick delete (without help from the SE team):

[image: can't quick-delete account]

seems to be a bug in either:

- the code that checks if a user voted/posted more than once

  - migrations might be the issue or the counter is actually set to **1**, and not **2** as it should be, based on the text in the help center

or

- the text in the Help center's account deletion page

  - The counter is actually set to **1** and the help text should read "If you have voted or posted *one or more times*" or even "*at all*", which in fact, the second half of that page seems to imply: "*If you have voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team*"

Is this valid or am I missing something?

**Edit**: For a visual, here's my Beer.SE profile:

[image]

Comment: Accepting an answer may count as a vote for this purpose, since it causes rep changes.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I didn't accept the answer. I was *going to*, but I only just created the account and asked this Meta question; I haven't voted or accepted. There is only a single question, and it's the one that was migrated from Skeptics.SE. I actually said this in the question :)

Comment: I got that. I just thought that your third paragraph was saying that you had accepted the answer.